# dropwizard: produce both html and json from the same class

Tags: java, dropwizard

Is there a way to control the output format from the client side?

I have a class which

```
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
```

and I want it to produce **json** when the client requests.

I can copy the class verbatim, replacing only the **@Path** and **@Produces** annotations, but this looks like a total waste.

I wonder if the client could append something like **&content-type=application/json** to the URL and have my server respond with json instead of html?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to annotate the resources as providing both HTML and JSON:

```
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

Then just make sure you have `MessageBodyWriter` implementations registered to handle the method's return type. Dropwizard's `JacksonMessageBodyProvider` should handle the JSON; if you're using Dropwizard Views, `ViewMessageBodyWriter` should handle the rest. Jersey will do the content negotiation with the client, provided your client has `application/json` in the request's `Accept` header.

Comment: how do I register MessageBodyWriter? My return type extends View; that was enough to produce html. how do I control the Accept header from the browser? thanks!

Comment: You don't need to register anything, really. It should just work.

Comment: As far as controlling the `Accept` header: you can't.